# Looping through data and setting IndexMatch formula based on cell value - too slow because of .getValue()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code which loops through my rows and depending on what the value is in Column 2, returns different types of IndexMatch formulas. My code works very well and puts the formulas in the relevant columns, however it is very slow.

I get a message that .getValue() is very heavy and therefore slows down the code.

Now I need to figure out how to improve the speed of the code but since I am new to coding, I am not particularly sure how to go at this problem.

Here is what I have:

```
function setFormulas() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //gets the workbook being used
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Open Requests"); //gets the active worksheet


  var sheetnametoWatch ="Open Requests"; //defines sheet 

  var columnnumbertoWatch = 14
  var valuetoWatch = ""
  var CostCenter = "'Open Requests'!"
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var datarange = sheet.getRange(11,2,lastrow -1,50).getValues()
  var row = 10

  for (i=0;i<datarange.length;i++){
    var rowID = 10 + i + 1

    if (datarange[i][0] == "CC"){
      var addedCell = '=CONCATENATE(F'+rowID+',N'+rowID+',K'+rowID+')';
      sheet.getRange(row + i+1,35).setFormula(addedCell);

      var MatchedCell = '=INDEX(Input!$Q:$Q,MATCH('+CostCenter+'$AI$'+rowID+',Input!$K:$K,0))';
      sheet.getRange(row + i+1,17).setFormula(MatchedCell); 

      sheet.getRange(row + i+1,18).setValue("kristin.j@ni.com")
    }
    else if (datarange[i][0] == "CC + TM1"){
      var addedCell = '=CONCATENATE(F'+rowID+',N'+rowID+',K'+rowID+')';
      sheet.getRange(row + i+1,35).setFormula(addedCell);

      var MatchedCell = '=INDEX(Input!$Q:$Q,MATCH('+CostCenter+'$AI$'+rowID+',Input!$K:$K,0))';
      sheet.getRange(row + i+1,17).setFormula(MatchedCell); 

      sheet.getRange(row + i+1,18).setValue("kristin.j@ni.com")
    }
    else if (datarange[i][0] == "GC"){
      sheet.getRange(row + i+1,18).setValue("kristin.j@ni.com")
    }

  }

 }
```

So as you can see, I am looping through the data and then depending on whether the column = CC, CC+TM1, GC it will set other cells equal to the relevant formula.

It would be great if somebody can help me in speeding up this process.

Comment: Read the article on Apps Script best practices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having some trouble following exactly what the code does, but at a high level, I think what you want to do is this: instead of setting formulas for particular cells as you cycle through your for loop, use the loop to figure out which cells should be set to which formulas and store that information. Then, at the end of the for loop, call `sheet.getRange(x,y).setFormula(Formula);` just a few times, perhaps once for each formula.

Does that seem like it could work?